# Modular arithmetic

Tags: cryptography, math, modular

I'm new to cryptography and modular arithmetic. So, I'm sure it's a silly question, but I can't help it.

How do I calculate *a* from 
     pow(*a*,**q**) = 1 (mod **p**), 
where **p** and **q** are known? I don't get the "1 (mod **p**)" part, it equals to 1, doesn't it? If so, than what is "mod **p**" about? 
Is this the same as 
     pow(*a*,**-q**) (mod **p**) = 1?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The (mod p) part refers not to the right hand side, but to the equality sign: it says that *modulo p, pow(a,q) and 1 are equal*. For instance, "modulo 10, 246126 and 7868726 are equal" (and they are also both equal to 6 modulo 10): **two numbers x and y are equal modulo p if they have the same remainder on dividing by p, or equivalently, if p divides x-y.**

Since you seem to be coming from a programming perspective, another way of saying it is that pow(a,q)%p=1, where "%" is the "remainder" operator as implemented in several languages (assuming that p>1).

You should read the Wikipedia article on [Modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), or any elementary number theory book (or even a cryptography book, since it is likely to introduce modular arithmetic).

To answer your other question: there is no general formula for finding such an *a* (to the best of my knowledge) in general. Assuming that p is prime, and using [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) to reduce q modulo p-1, and assuming that q divides p-1 (or else no such *a* exists), you can produce such an *a* by taking a [primitive root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) of p and raising it to the power (p-1)/q. [And more generally, when p is not prime, you can reduce q modulo φ(p), then assuming it divides φ(p) and you know a primitive root (say r) mod p, you can take r to the power of φ(p)/q, where φ is [the totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) -- this comes from [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).]

Comment: Woah! I am glad that you are here to answer these sort of questions!

Answer (score 5):

Not silly at all, as **this is the basis for public-key encryption.** You can find an excellent discussion on this at http://home.scarlet.be/~ping1339/congr.htm#The-equation-a%3Csup%3Ex.

PKI works by choosing `p` and `q` that are large and [*relatively prime*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime).  One (say `p`) becomes your private key and the other (`q`) is your public key.  The encryption is "broken" if an attacker guesses `p`, given `a`<sup>`q`</sup> (the encrypted message) and `q` (your public key).

So, to answer your question:

> `a`<sup>`q`</sup> = 1 mod `p`

This means `a`<sup>`q`</sup> is a number that leaves a remainder of 1 when divided by `p`.  We don't care about the integer portion of the quotient, so we can write:

> `a`<sup>`q`</sup> / `p` = `n` + 1/`p`

for *any integer value of `n`*.  If we multiply both sides of the equation by `p`, we have:

> `a`<sup>`q`</sup> = `np` + 1

Solving for `a` we have:

> `a` = (`np`+1)<sup>1/`q`</sup>

The final step is to find a value of `n` that generates the original value of  `a`.  I don't know of any way to do this other than trial and error -- which equates to a "brute force" attempt to break the encryption.